# JavaScript - Wait until multiple ajax requests are done then do something

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, timeout

I have two ajax calls in JavaScript that add content to the page asynchronously. I need to create a "timeout" function (or something similar) that waits until they're both done loading to then execute more code. Here is what I have so far

https://jsfiddle.net/qcu5asnj/

```
<div class='resultsSection'>
    Example
</div>

<script>

var loading_first = "loading";
var first_ajax = {
  url: 'https://example.com/load.php?q=fast',
  type: "GET",
  success: function( data ) {
        console.log("success");
         $(".resultsSection").append(data);
         loading_first = "done";
  }
};
$.ajax( first_ajax );

var loading_second = "loading";
var second_ajax = {
  url: 'https://example.com/load.php?q=slow',
  type: "GET",
  success: function( data ) {
        console.log("success");
        $(".resultsSection").append(data);
        loading_second = "done";
  }
};
$.ajax( second_ajax );

// Need to create a function that waits until both are done. I know this is wrong
if((loading_first == "done") && (loading_second == "done")){
        console.log("Both done loading, execute more code here");
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the promises returned by $.ajax in variables and use Promise.all()

```js
const req1 = $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(data => {
  console.log('First request done')
  return data
})

const req2 = $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2').then(data => {
  console.log('Second request done')
  return data
})

Promise.all([req1, req2]).then(results=>{
   console.log('All done')
   console.log('Combined results',results)
}).catch(err=> console.log('Ooops one of the requests failed'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use this approach. My example was simplified, but with my code I can't do it this way. Is there another way?

Comment: Well even if these requests are done in separate functions you can also return the same promise from those functions and do it this way. This is the most practical way of doing it regardless of the code complexity